# Two chunks side by side with knitr markdown

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

With `Rmarkdown`, how could we do to get two chunk outputs side by side ?

I have naively tried this which doesn't work:

````
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
```{r one, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
......
......
```
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
```{r two, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
......
......
```        
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
````

Actually, more precisely, I want to generate two figures side by side. I know this is possible with only one figure using `mfrow()` for classical plots or `grid.arrange()` for ggplots, but I'd like to include two html legends, one below each figure.

NB: I'm rather ignorant in HTML.

Comment: In the new RStudio presentations, you can do this by separating the two parts by `***`.  Might look at how they did it and go from there.

Comment: Good to know that @AriB.Friedman. But actually I intend to convert the html report in docx using pandoc. And more precisely I want to put some figures side by side, not any text (I'm going to edit my post to add this precision).

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question that provides some possible code solutions and a link to the Docco standard style, which shows a nice example:

[2 Column Report in R Markdown - Render HTML aside Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237190/2-column-report-in-r-markdown-render-html-aside-data-frame)