# How make 2 column layout in R markdown when rendering pdf?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown

When rendering html documents with rmarkdown there are ways to make a two columns layout, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753897/2-column-section-in-r-markdown)

Is there an easy way to render a pdf document with two column layout? Is there an example code somewhere?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

New pandoc version have made this easier since my original answer. According to [pandoc's manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex), you can now specify classoptions directly in the YAML front matter:

```
---
classoption:
- twocolumn
---
```

The new div notation also allows for inserting two column sections anywhere in the document, working for most formats

```
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="40%"}

contents...

:::
::: {.column width="60%"}

contents...

:::
::::::::::::::
```

## Original answer

You can use the article option `twocolumn` to format the whole document in two columns. Add this to your yaml front matter:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"
    ]
---
```

Comment: ok, I see where the second column is supposed to be but all the content is in the first column. How to put content to second column?

Comment: So to start a twocolumn section, you just use \twocolumn, but how do you set it back to onecolumn for subsequent sections (like figures, for instance)?

Comment: you can use \onecolumn but fine tuning this is hard. You'll find more help on tex.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

More succinctly:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
classoption: twocolumn
---
```

Answer (score 7):

Regarding switching between one and two columns modes in pdf the following snippets work for me

To two column mode:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("\\twocolumn")
```
````

To one column mode:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("\\onecolumn")
```
````

Comment: This is starting a new page for me each time I change. I can't switch on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

Credit for this answer found here: https://timmurphy.org/2010/06/23/adding-a-two-column-section-to-a-latex-document/

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
First Column Goodies.\\
More First Column Goodies.\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Second Column Goodies.\\
More Second Column Goodies.\\
\end{minipage}
```

Note: VERY important that there is no space between the /end{minipage} and the next \begin{minipage} (not counting comments). Otherwise LaTeX will not render the columns side by side.

Comment: This one has the benefit of working with xelatex as well.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me with pdf_document

Answer (score 2):

In addition to scoa's answer, in order to give the columns more space you can add a value to the `header-includes:`, for example:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    ...
header-includes:
- \setlength{\columnsep}{18pt}
---
```