# How to make multi-column Layout in R Markdown when rendering PDF?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808612/how-make-2-column-layout-in-r-markdown-when-rendering-pdf) is a great answer on how to do a **2-column** layout in R-Markdown when rendering PDF.

Basically the answer is 'add the following to the header':

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
classoption: twocolumn
---
```

But how do I make it **three columns or more**?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a html file with multiple columns, you could use the CSS grid layout:

```
---
output: html_document
---

:::: {style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 20% 50% 20%; grid-column-gap: 5%; "}

::: {}

contents...

:::

::: {}

contents...

:::

::: {}

contents...

:::

::::
```

If you want to use four (or more) columns:

```
:::: {style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: pc1% pc2% pc3% pc4%; grid-column-gap: pgap%; "}
```

Adjust the column size and gap percentages to your needs.

This won't work if you replace *html_doument* with *pdf_document*. If you are particularly interested in generating a pdf output, a workaround would be to open the html file with a browser and then printing it to a pdf file.