# Two-column mode in standard R Markdown for pandoc pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, multiple-columns, document, pandoc

I'm looking for a solution to the RMarkdown 2-column question. The columns.sty works great in Beamer but not in article or document mode. What I'm looking for is a way to switch from full width to two column text in which the RMarkdown parameters are recognized (minipage doesn't allow this, apparently) and where I can execute a chunk for a plot or table or pander output, and then back again to full width, w/o creating a new page as with \twocolumn \onecolumn. The classoption: twopage approach doesn't work for me for some reason [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724367/how-to-make-multi-column-layout-in-r-markdown-when-rendering-pdf). Am I asking too much? Any help with a fully working example would be great!

Here's an example of the use of the class option 'twocolumn' in the yaml section. A two column section starts with \begin{minipage} and ends with \end{minipage}. This will produce a two column section but, as far as I can tell, this also creates a latex-only section because RMarkdown parameters (e.g. # ... for a heading) create an error on rendering to a pdf (that's what I want).

````
title: "Two column test"
author: "David Stevens"
date: "10/19/2020"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
classoption: twocolumn
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

### Left column  

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
First Column Goodies.\\  
More First Column Goodies.\\  
### Left column\\  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
 Second Column Goodies.\\
 More Second Column Goodies.\\
\end{minipage}
````

Produces the error

output file: Two-Column-Tester.knit.md

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.81 #
## Left column

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Two-Column-Tester.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Two-Column-Tester.log for more info.
Execution halted

The line ### Two column renders fine outside the two-column section but when moved inside the two column section throws an error

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider work with existing styles? The [rticles](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=rticles) packages has a large number of those. I by coincidence I just updated the 'gallery' of styles included in that package which you can browse [at this link](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/rticles-gallery/).  There is also one [large aggregated gif with all](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rticles-gallery/blob/master/docs/all.gif).

We also created [the pinp package](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=pinp) are derived version of the 'pnas' style in `rticles`. I use that in several packages for the vignette.