# Placing table next to plot in R Markdown (to pdf / latex)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, xtable

Is it possible to place a table generated with the `xtable` (or alternatively the `pander`) package and a generated plot side-by-side in R markdown knitting to pdf while the rest of the document *is not* in columns? The following simple example hopefully illustrates the idea:

````
\begin{multicols}{2}
```{r}
plot(cars)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
library('xtable')
print(xtable(head(cars,5)), type = "latex")
```
\end{multicols}
````

However, this does not produce the plot. I know that solutions exist using knitr (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/two-column-layout-with-text-and-knitr-chunk?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) and for R markdown knitting to HTML (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753897/2-column-section-in-r-markdown?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) but I don't get them to work for R markdown to pdf.

Comment: You could cconsider using raw LaTeX within the R Markdown file using something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions

Answer (score 2):

the `gridExtra` package works for this without having to go into LaTeX hell.  Use the `grid.arrange` function for side by side charts and what-not.

Works on html and PDF outputs.

Comment: This is an `R` package BTW

Comment: In its current form, this is more of a comment. You should try and expand on the answer so that it provides a complete solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @nycrefugee this already opens some more opportunities. However, there seem to be some problems with `xtable` outputs. If I use the following code:

```
library('gridExtra')
library('grid')
library('xtable')
library('lattice')

p = xyplot(1~1)
t = textGrob( print(xtable(head(cars,5)),
                    type = "latex", label = "test")
            )

grid.arrange(p, t, ncol=2)
```

it produces the following output when compiled to pdf, i.e. the table is shown above the two grobs:

[PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCal.png)

Comment: If you want to provide more information, please edit the question rather than adding it as an answer.