# Separate side by side tables in R markdown

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown

I have created two tables in R that I would like to put side by side in conditional chunks in an R Markdown document. I managed to get the tables side by side, but they are now attached to each other. However, I would like them to have some space in between. Any ideas?

````
<TABLE BORDER=0>
<TR>
<TD>
```{r, eval=('May' %in%years), echo = FALSE}
table.MAY.odd
```
</TD>
<br>
<TD>
```{r, eval=('May' %in%years), echo = FALSE}
table.MAY.even
```
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
````

Comment: It's hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We don't know what `table.MAY.odd` is--a data frame? Also, generally HTML tags are lowercase, and the `border` attribute has been deprecated for some time now

Comment: Also, they're attached to each other because they're adjacent cells in a single `<table>` element. Using `<table>` elements to build layouts is a pretty outdated method, since you have better control using CSS. Would a two-column layout in your Rmarkdown not work? Such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31753897/5325862)