# Insert two columns into R Markdown for Word ouput

Tags: r-markdown, multiple-columns, pandoc, cpu-word

I would like to insert a two column section in my R Markdown text and output into Word:

```
Paragraph

Column 1        Column 2
Text            Text

Paragraph
```

How would I do this? I tried using the [HTML method on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753897/2-column-section-in-r-markdown) with no luck.

Comment: You may find useful David Gohel's [officedown](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) & [officer](https://github.com/davidgohel/officer) packages.  
Place the content in a multi-column layout/block and adjust its arguments `widths` and `space`. If interested, check out the [officedown template](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/word/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd)

Comment: You are suppose to be able to make a `.Docx` file formatted in the output you wanted, and then you that as a reference docx in your Rmarkdown, but trying to get it to format has not been successful for me. [Reference link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html)

Comment: @DanielJachetta I am using a reference docx, but I don't think you can specify a two column format in that docx

Comment: You can, but I was not able to do a paragraph, 2 columns, paragraph. Rmarkdown wouldn’t format